# actionBarTheme conflicts with popupMenuStyle

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I noticed that when setting background in actionBarTheme style attribute together with setting background in popupMenuStyle style attribute :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
</style>
```

The background in the actionBarTheme effects the actionbar but also the                       text in each menu option.

[image]

Any idea how to solve this ? Thanks.

Comment: are you using toolbar?

Comment: @SohailZahid No. android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

i face the same issue while using toolbar.
Fixed like this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar                  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/themedDarkToolbarBackGroundColor"
        android:titleTextAppearance="@color/White"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MenuThemeDark"/>
```

use style like this

```
     <style name="MenuThemeDark" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/DarkThemeConsListTitleName</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/DarkThemeColorBackground</item>
    </style>
```